# I'm reciving Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): err.response is undefined in my React app

Tags: reactjs

When i type a user login, a user password and after that i click on sign in i recive this error (Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): err.response is undefined in my React app) on line 48. Someone could help me?

```
const [showErrorMessage, setShowErrorMessage] = useState(false)
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('')

  const onSubmit = (data, e) => {
    e.target.reset()
    setShowErrorMessage(false)
    const response = api.post('login', {
      user: data.usuario,
      password: data.senha,
    })
    response
      .then((res) => {
        localStorage.setItem('producao-token', res.data.split(':')[0])
        localStorage.setItem('producao-type', res.data.split(':')[1])
        localStorage.setItem('producao-user', res.data.split(':')[2])
        localStorage.removeItem('logout')
        return res.data.split(':')[1]
      })
      .then((type) => {
        if (type === '2') {
          history.push({
            pathname: '/producao/usuario',
          })
        } else {
          history.push({
            pathname: '/producao',
          })
        }
      })

        .catch((err) => {
LINE 48 setErrorMessage(err.response.data)
        setShowErrorMessage(true)
      })
  }
```

Comment: Did you try to log the error? That error simply means that response is undefined, so the err object is probably what you expect it is